# Android getAccelerometer Values

Tags: android, game-physics, android-sensors

Im trying to have a better understanding of Values given by getAccelerometer. So I made a log report of X,Y and Z axis.
my first question is why this values are not initialized 0 ?
because when the device is left on the table the following values are produced:

```
09-07 21:25:00.929: V/SERVICE:X, Y, Z:(22548): -0.48858398,0.6706055,,10.768008
09-07 21:25:01.079: V/SERVICE:X, Y, Z:(22548): -0.4790039,0.68018556,,10.787168
09-07 21:25:01.279: V/SERVICE:X, Y, Z:(22548): -0.48858398,0.6610254,,10.787168
09-07 21:25:01.479: V/SERVICE:X, Y, Z:(22548): -0.45984375,0.6706055,,10.777588
09-07 21:25:01.679: V/SERVICE:X, Y, Z:(22548): -0.4790039,0.6610254,,10.796748
09-07 21:25:01.879: V/SERVICE:X, Y, Z:(22548): -0.4790039,0.6610254,,10.806328
09-07 21:25:02.084: V/SERVICE:X, Y, Z:(22548): -0.4790039,0.6706055,,10.796748
09-07 21:25:02.284: V/SERVICE:X, Y, Z:(22548): -0.46942383,0.68018556,,10.796748
09-07 21:25:02.479: V/SERVICE:X, Y, Z:(22548): -0.48858398,0.6610254,,10.787168
```

my second question is why everybody keep telling me I can not calculate a few meter movement of device by calculating A=From getAccelerometer and T= time from event occurring.
where is the problem that I m not considering ?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Addressing your two questions:

1. I wouldn't expect the accelerometer to read 0 because at least you should see the acceleration of gravity, which is what you're seeing: x,y are about 0, z is about 9.8 (plus about 1 unit of noise).
2. To get position from acceleration you need to integrate twice. Think back to calculus, when you integrate you get a constant of integration, which you have no way of knowing. Here's an example: acceleration and time can tell me how much my speed has changed, for example if I slowed down by 10 mph. What it can't tell me is how fast I'm going, ie it can't tell me if I'm in a car and went from 60 mph to 50 mph, or if I'm in an airplane and went from 580 mph to 570 mph. You will have the same problem again going from velocity to position.

EDIT:

Answering your questions in the comment:

[image]

1) Gravity always points towards the planet, so if your phone is flat on a table, like you described, then I would expect G to be in mostly the +Z direction. If you're holding your phone in your hand in front of you then I would expect G to be mostly in the -Y direction.

2) If you know that the initial velocity is 0 then it's theoretically possible. You're looking at an algorithm called *numerical integration* which looks like this:

```
Numerical_Integration() :

vel = 0;
prevTime = getTime();
while (true) {
    currTime = getTime();
    vel += getAccelleration() * (currTime - prevTime);
    prevTime = currTime;
}
```

If the acceleration is constant (or almost constant) then this will work fine, but if the acceleration is jittery (like in your hand which is shaking a little) then you need this loop to run very very very fast. Usually software isn't fast enough and you need special hardware to do it, otherwise it will think it's moved 5 m when it's just been sitting on a table. I don't know how much accuracy you need for what you're doing, or how good the Android accelerometers are, or maybe they even have the special hardware inside them.

So definitely you should play around with it - if nothing else you'll learn a whole bunch - and read the Android accelerometers documentation for more ideas.

Hope that helps, good luck!

Comment: thanks for the reply, but 1) shouldnt gravity just affect Z? and 10% of noise isnt unacceptable for Z ? 2)what If I know the initial Velocity is 0 ? what then ?